# mgo: how to update a specific array in a document

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mgo

I have this document inside my database:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "53dc97bf91f1f933e15d6fb1",
    "attributes": {
      "chilled": false,
      "flammable": false,
      "food": false,
      "fragile": false,
      "frozen": false,
      "hot": false,
      "outsized": false
    },
    "createdAt": "02/08/14 09:48:16",
    "customer": "53d68bc091f1f933e15d6f90",
    "location": [
      {
        "count": 0,
        "warehouse": "53db430c91f1f933e15d6fa6"
      },
      {
        "count": 34,
        "warehouse": "53db430c91g1f933e45d6fa4"
      },
    ],
    "name": "test",
    "type": "stored",
    "updatedAt": ""
  }
]
```

How can i update the location array if i know the warehouse Id?
This is what i have now

```
coll := p.GetDb().C("product")
    changes := bson.M {
        "location": bson.M {
            "$elemMatch": bson.M {
                "warehouse": bson.ObjectIdHex(warehouseId),
            },
        },
        "$set": bson.M {
            "location.$.count": 4,
        }, 
    }
    
    err := coll.UpdateId(bson.ObjectIdHex(productId), changes)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(res, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }
```

But get this error:

> The dollar ($) prefixed field '$elemMatch' in 'location.$elemMatch' is not valid for storage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You wrote this the wrong way around. The match on the warehouse "id" value belongs in the "query" portion of your statement and not in the "update" section. As such, you don't want the `UpdateId` variant, but the [`Update`](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Update) as it allows a wider query selection:

```
query := bson.M{
    "_id": bson.ObjectIdHex(productId),
    "location.warehouse": bson.ObjectIdHex(warehouseId)
}

update := bson.M{
    "$set": bson.M{
        "location.$.count": 4
    }
}

err := coll.Update(query,update)
```

Also note that the the ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) form is fine here as your selector for the array element is just a singular field. You typically only need [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) when there is more that one field in the array to establish the match.