# Error updating a particular object in an array of documents in mongo

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query

I have a mongo document that looks like this -

```
{
  "id": 3737737,
  "name": "usa",
  "count": 1399,
  "schools": [
    {
      "id": 338383,
      "count": 899,
      "state": "new york"
    },
    {
      "id": 11233,
      "count": 500,
      "state": "phily"
    },
    
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to update for a particular school in the schools array if I know the document id and school id but I can't seem to get this to work.

This is what I am doing

```
query := bson.M{
            "id": "3737737",
            "schools.id":"11233",
        }

update := Changes{Count: 900}
err := col.Update(query,update)
```

PS: `Changes` is the struct that holds data that can be updated for a school.

When I run the above code, its the `count` outside the `schools` array that gets updated.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: use positional update operator, `{ "schools.$.count": 900 }`

Comment: I am using a struct, how do I do this?

Comment: i don't know more about `go`, but you can refer this similar question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093667/mgo-how-to-update-a-specific-array-in-a-document).

Comment: @shekwo try after changing `Changes{Count: 900}` to `Changes{"schools.count": 900}`.